# Two same tables with different sizes on different databases

Tags: sql-server

We had an issue on one of the table (Example: Table1) where i have got to transfer all the data on to another database (Example Table2). Both databases on same server and table 1 is having same indexes as table 2 and also the fragmentation levels on indexes are also same.

everything went OK but i have noticed some differences.

Table1 (Old Table) occupied 200GB where as table2 (New Table) occupied arround 110GB. There is huge difference. I have check indexes for any fragmentation levels and there is nothing like that which will give 90GB space.

Please give me some suggestions where i can check anything else on.?

Comment: Maybe you have DATA_COMPRESSION enabled on one index

Comment: What's the cluster size for each disk? How fragmented are the *files*?  How full are they? If the source files were only 55% full, the target would be 110GB

Comment: @Lucky125111 Datacompression is not enabled.

Comment: @Panagiotis How can i find cluster size of each disc.??

Comment: From the Windows Disk Management tool. I suspect the real "culprit" is the free space in the files/databases though. Did you check it? How did you transfer the data? Backup/restore and attach/detach will preserve empty space. Copying data with SSIS or any other import/export technique won't

Comment: Significant space differences may be the old table has more unused space than the new one. This may depend on how the old table was loaded versus the new one or index fill factors. Run `EXEC sp_spaceused N'dbo.Table1;EXEC sp_spaceused N'dbo.Table2;` to see if the unused space is different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. i have transferred data using ssis.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can i get this sorted. All i want is to reduce the original table size to 100.

Comment: @user9192401 as others and I have said, there's *nothing* wrong with this. One table has preallocated space, because it's used all the time. The other doesn't, because it was loaded a single time. Perhaps. that's how the DBA configured it. That means the production table doesn't have to allocate new space when it wants to insert new data. If you shrink it, next time the file is full the server will have to increase it and allocate new space

Comment: @user9192401 read [What’s So Bad About Shrinking Databases with DBCC SHRINKDATABASE?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/) first. It explains why you shouldn't rush to shrink the database, not before understanding how much space is actually needed for day-to-day operations. The documentation on shrinking databases [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much mate